# Can two version of MS Test Controller co-exist on a single machine

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, tfs

I have two version of VS installed on my machine . I have few compatibility issues while Configuring Test Controller (2012) . I get the following error message

Test controller cannot communicate with the controller due to version mismatch

By the message I understood that there is a version mismatch since my TFS version 2010 and I cannot change the TFS version due to some technical difficulties .

I want to understand two point

1) Can two version of Test Controller co-exist on a single machine?

2) The error message above states a mismatch , should I try to open TFS in VS 2012  or is that the TFS server in which TFS is hosted should have same version of Test Controller .

I request any one to kindly help me at the earliest ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 - I don't believe this is possible.
2 - You must use the test controller version that matches your TFS version

You can install additional version of VS on the test controller to support running different version of VS testing frameworks.

Or if you only want to install the latest version of VS on the controller you can use assembly bindings to redirect the older versions to the latest:

http://www.dotnetcatch.com/2015/10/01/tfs-2010-to-2015-upgrade-codedui-feature-test-builds/

Comment: Hi Chief, I have uninstalled existing Test Controller 2012 on my machine and re-installed the Test Controller 2010 as my TFS is 2010 and I was unable to register any Test Agent of 2010 or able to register Test Controller 2012 with TFS 2010 .

Comment: It is understood that we need to have Test Controller and TFS both of same version , Thanks for your help again